# How to prevent component from unmounting immediately when using React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-transition-group

I am using react-transition-group's  tag to create animations between routes using react-router-v4. I am using  tags to switch between routes in my code based off of changes in state. The issue that I am running into is, when a  is triggered, the component immediately unmounts, before giving the exit animation time to play out. The new route animates in correctly.

I have tried to solve this by following this page on the React Transition Group site: https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/with-react-router

It acknowledges the problem that I am having with the components immediately unmounting, but my solution does not seem to be working.

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Dashboard', Component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/detailedview', name: 'DetailedView', Component: DetailedView },
  { path: '/dashboardloop', name: 'DashboardLoop', Component: DashboardLoop },
]

function Example() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <>
        <Container className="container">
          {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
            <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
              {({ match }) => (
                <CSSTransition
                  in={match != null}
                  timeout={500}
                  classNames="page"
                  unmountOnExit
                >
                  <div className="page">
                    <Component />
                  </div>
                </CSSTransition>
              )}
            </Route>
          ))}
        </Container>
      </>
    </Router>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <Example/>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any help would be appreciated with this! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, you might already solved this on your own, but for the record to people googling for this problem: Check your css.

CSSTransition relies on four css classes (as stated in the documentation):

```
/* Starting style of enter animation, i.e when element is still invisible */
.page-transition-enter{
}

/* How the element will look on the page + transition (which does the animation) goes here*/
.page-transition-enter-active{
}

/* Start of exit animation, usually how the element looks on the page */
.page-transition-exit{
}

/*The end-style of exit-animation + transition */
.page-transition-exit-active{
}
```

A simple transition example from React Transition Group documentation (http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition):

```
.page-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.page-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
.page-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.page-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

As your element unmounts without animation but animates when entering, it seems that you are most likely missing something from the last two classes. Or missing either or both classes altogether.